# Custom notification template with Ionic

Tags: android, ios, notifications, ionic-framework

I'd like to display custom notifications that embeds buttons (just like a music player controls) using ionic framework, allowing the user to have a choice when clicking the notification.

I can't find any official (or unofficial) documentation about that, and I don't even know if it is possible.

Has anyone successfully created a custom notification template with ionic framework ?

Comment: Did you found any solution? I'm stuck at same problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using an ionicPopup with an custom template.

Here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/nicon-dev/pen/EPYeGJ

or:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

  $scope.openPopup = function() {

    var customTemplate =
      '<ion-toggle>enable</ion-toggle>' +
      '<label class="item item-input"><input type="text" placeholder="your address"></label>';

    $ionicPopup.show({
      template: customTemplate,
      title: 'alternative location',
      subTitle: 'select this option if GPS is unavailable',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        //type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {

        }
      }, {
        text: '<b>Save</b>',
        type: 'button-positive',
        onTap: function(e) {
          
        }
      }]
    });

  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic Pull to Refresh</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content class="padding">
    <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="openPopup()">open popup</button>
  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

$ionicPopup docs: [HERE](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this isn't what I'm looking for.
What I'm trying to achieve is to display a native notification with buttons embedded in it, not an in-app popup.

You can see an example of what I would like to do [here](http://media02.hongkiat.com/android-notification-features/dismiss-all-notifications.jpg) (The "dismiss now" button)

Comment: What you are looking for then are push messages. Have a look at [Ionic Push Service](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-overview) for a starting point

Comment: I know this is the service I'm looking for, what I'm asking here is HOW to design a notification allowing it to feature buttons leading to different actions. I haven't found any piece of documentation about this.